# directory structures for zend multisites

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to create a multisites using zf2 that will run on subdomains.So can anyone advise the directory structure that needs to be created and the codes cannot be written again and again for each subdomains website for same features that multisite shares.

Please advise.

Comment: are you wanting a zf2 or zf1 solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a multisite app in ZF1, this is the folder structure I used.

```
application
    configs
        sites
            domingod    <-- these
            artofwood   <-- are
            freedoms    <-- sites
        application.ini
    layouts
        scripts
            sites
                domingod
                artofwood
                freedoms
                    default.phtml    <-- Sites layout
        default.phtml    <-- default layout used if sites layout cannot be found
        admin.phtml      <-- admin layout
    modules
        default
            controllers
            forms
            models
            views
                helpers
                scripts
                    index
                        index.phtml    <-- Default layout file
                    sites
                        domingod
                        artofwood
                        freedoms
                            index
                                index.phtml    <-- Sites layout file, overrides default layout above
            Bootstrap.php
        ...
```

In order to get this to work I needed to use a couple of plugins.

Firstly I get the site from the database, I use doctrine ORM so you may need to change this to use zend db.

```
class FreedomS_Zend_Controller_Plugin_GetSite extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $this->_httpHost    = $request->getHttpHost();
        $this->_scheme      = $request->getScheme();

        $httpHostArray = explode('.', $this->_httpHost);
        $this->_prefix = array_shift($httpHostArray);
        $this->_domainName = array_shift($httpHostArray);
        $this->_topLevelDomain = implode('.', $httpHostArray);


        $this->_fullDomainName = $this->_domainName . '.' . $this->_topLevelDomain;
        Zend_Registry::set('prefix',            $this->_prefix);
        Zend_Registry::set('domainName',        $this->_domainName);
        Zend_Registry::set('fullDomainName',    $this->_fullDomainName);
        Zend_Registry::set('topLevelDomain',    $this->_topLevelDomain);
        Zend_Registry::set('scheme',            $this->_scheme);
        Zend_Registry::set('baseUrl',           $this->_scheme . '://' . $this->_httpHost . '/');

        $site = Model_Doctrine_SitesTable::getInstance()->getOneByDomain($this->_fullDomainName); // Get site from database using doctrine

        if (is_array($site) && array_key_exists('siteId', $site)) {
            Zend_Registry::set('siteId', $site['siteId']);
            Zend_Registry::set('site', $site);
            $currency = new Zend_Currency($site['locale']); // get currency for site
            Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Currency', $currency);
        } else {
            Zend_Registry::set('siteId', null);
            Zend_Registry::set('site', array());
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly I need ZF to read the correct files for the site, note that the site id is stored in zend registry by above plugin.  I have used strings for the site id such as freedoms and domingod, this keeps things more readable in the directory structure.

```
class FreedomS_Zend_Controller_Plugin_LayoutPicker extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $module = $request->getModuleName();

          Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',  'text/html;charset=utf-8');

        switch ($module) {
            case 'author': // author and admin have access to the admin area and have a different layout to the sites
            case 'admin':
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('admin');

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headTitle('Direct Sites Admin');

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink(Array('rel' => 'icon', 'href' => '/images/direct_links_icon.gif', 'type' => 'image/x-icon'));
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink(Array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'href' => '/images/direct_links_icon.gif', 'type' => 'image/x-icon'));

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/admin.css');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/sites/overlay.css');

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery_1.7.2.js');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery.tools.min.js');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-ui.min.js');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('/js/admin.js');

                $authStorage = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->username = $authStorage->storage['firstName'] . ' ' . $authStorage->storage['surname'];
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->date = date('l, j F Y');

                break;
            default:  // sites
                $layout = Model_Doctrine_LayoutsTable::getInstance()->getLayout(Zend_Registry::get('siteId'));  // get sites layout from database

                if (isset($layout['layout'])) {
                    $layoutFile = '/sites/' .  Zend_Registry::get('siteId') . '/' . $layout['layout'];

                    if (file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts' . $layoutFile . '.phtml')) {
                        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout($layoutFile);
                    } else {
                        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('default');
                    }
                } else {
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('default');
                }

                if (isset($layout['docType'])) {
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->doctype($layout['ZendDoctypes']['docType']);
                } else {
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
                }

                if (isset($layout['title'])) {
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headTitle($layout['title']);
                }

                if (isset($layout['favIcon'])) {
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink(Array('rel' => 'icon', 'href' => $layout['favIcon'], 'type' => 'image/x-icon'));
                    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink(Array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'href' => $layout['favIcon'], 'type' => 'image/x-icon'));
                }

                if (isset($layout['Sites']['Metacontent']) && is_array($layout['Sites']['Metacontent']) && !empty($layout['Sites']['Metacontent'])) {
                    foreach ($layout['Sites']['Metacontent'] as $metatag) {
                        $methodName = $metatag['Metatags']['method'];
                        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
                            ->getView()
                            ->headMeta()
                            ->$methodName($metatag['tagContent'], $metatag['content']);
                    }
                }

                if (isset($layout['Sites']['Scripts']) && is_array($layout['Sites']['Scripts']) && !empty($layout['Sites']['Scripts'])) {
                    foreach ($layout['Sites']['Scripts'] as $script) {
                        $scriptLink = '/js/' . $script['script'];
                        if (file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public_html' . $scriptLink)) {
                            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
                                ->getView()
                                ->headScript()
                                ->appendFile($scriptLink);
                        }
                    }
                }

                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/sites/common.css');
                if (isset($layout['Sites']['Stylesheets']) && is_array($layout['Sites']['Stylesheets']) && !empty($layout['Sites']['Stylesheets'])) {
                    foreach ($layout['Sites']['Stylesheets'] as $stylesheet) {
                        $styleSheetLink =  '/css/sites/' . Zend_Registry::get('siteId') . '/' . $stylesheet['styleSheet'];
                        if (file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public_html' . $styleSheetLink)) {
                            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
                                ->getView()
                                ->headLink()
                                ->appendStylesheet($styleSheetLink);
                        } else {
                            $styleSheetLink =  '/css/sites/' . $stylesheet['styleSheet'];
                            if (file_exists(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public_html' . $styleSheetLink)) {
                            Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
                                ->getView()
                                ->headLink()
                                ->appendStylesheet($styleSheetLink);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
        }

    }
}
```

My sites table on database

```
siteId  varchar(32)
domain  varchar(255)
site    varchar(255)
emailAddress    varchar(255)
address     text 
telNo   varchar(32)    
welcomeText     varchar(50) 
vatNo   varchar(12) 
vatRate     tinyint(2)    
vatTitle    varchar(10)  
locale  varchar(5)
```

My layout table

```
siteId  varchar(32)      
layout  varchar(32)
docTypeId   int(11)
title   varchar(100)
favIcon     varchar(255)
```

Please bear in mind this is all in ZF1 so it will need changing for ZF2.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Kind regards

Garry

Comment: Thanks for the directory structure,but I am not familiar with zf1 much.well Thanks for your support.